Ghost film involving the background of scenes lining up to create the appearance of a person, and then that person moving
I watched a trailer somewhere in the last year or so for a horror/thriller film in English. The protagonist (female adult, unsure of the ethnicity) is being haunted, with the haunting manifesting itself with seeming optical illusions where they're walking around the room until they pause, and it turns out that the various objects in the room, from the perspective of the camera, line up to be like a human form behind them, seemingly just an optical illusion... and then suddenly the figure moves, an actual being. Unfortunately, I don't remember exactly what happens next, as I think the trailer immediately jumped from the scene after the reveal. There were at least 2-3 such scenes as I recall it.

The Night House 2021.
See the trailer here:



The scene you're remembering is at 2 minutes 2 seconds and ends at 2 minutes 6 seconds in the trailer.

From the Corridor Crew review posted two more



Good find. :-D I was just finishing up my own self-answer on it. Turns out I hadn't seen the trailer, but rather the Corridor Crew breakdown.

Its an interesting movie. I also found the Corridor Crew video first.
